# Arduino function keeps looping after calling other function

Tags: c++, arduino

I am a beginner to coding with c++ and I have been trying to make the led pin blink via input from serial but when I tell it to turn off, it keeps blinking. I think the problem is at the bottom of the code.

```
int ledPin = 13;
String readString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Serial Blinker (Input 'on' to blink and 'off' to stop blinking)");
}
void loop() {
  readString = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;
  }
  readString.trim();
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    if (readString == "on") {
      Serial.println("switching on");
      next();
    }
  }
}
void next() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(500);
  readString = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;
  }
  readString.trim();
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    if (readString == "off") {
      Serial.println("switching off");
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 int ledPin = 13;
String readString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Serial Blinker (Input 'on' to blink and 'off' to stop blinking)");
}
void loop() {
  readString = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;
  }
  readString.trim();
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    if (readString == "on") {
      Serial.println("switching on");
      next();
    }
    else if(readString == "off"){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}
void next() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(500);
   readString = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;
  }
  readString.trim();

    if (readString == "off") {
      Serial.print("off");
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      off();
    }
    else {
            next();
    }

}

void off(){
  Serial.print("in off");
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

}
```